# Malliavin Derivative

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, malliavin-calculus

**Motivation** : We know that, if the randomness in the system is due to Brownian Motion then any *contingent claim* with mean zero can be written as Ito integral. (Of course, we need to have boundedness properties for claim.) Now, I am interested to know the *strategy* (the integrand of stochastic integral) explicitly for given claim. Consider simple claim such as $f(B_T)$ where $f$ is smooth and bounded function. Is there any explicit formula which can give process $Z$ such that $\int_0^T Z_t dB_t = f(B_T)-\mathbb{E}[f(B_T)]$ ?

**Attempt** : I tried to use Ito formula to calculate $Z$. However it works only when $f$ is linear. In other cases, I don't have much progress. Although, Martingales Representation Theorem asserts the existence of $Z$, it doesn't provide a way to explicitly calculate it. I would like to know how to make *calculations*. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is a consequence from the [Clarke-Ocone Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clark%E2%80%93Ocone_theorem), and uses Malliavin derivative. See also the Clarke-Ocone formula paragraphe [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malliavin_calculus). If you want a technical reference, see this [introductory course](http://www.crm.cat/en/Activities/Documents/RR-4718.pdf), mainly theorem 1 p. 18.